# xml equivalent of json_decode function

Tags: php, json, google-maps

i have the following code written in php which makes use of json to find the place details and is working fine.

```
<?php
function search_place_details($location)
{

   $locationclean = str_replace (" ", "+", $location);
   $details_url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=" . $locationclean . "&key=MY-GOOGLE-API-KEY";
   $du = file_get_contents($details_url);

   $getDetails = json_decode(utf8_encode($du),true);
   if ($getDetails['status']=="OK")
   {
   $a = $getDetails['results'][0]['types'];
   echo implode(" ",$a)."<br>";
   }
   else
   {
   echo "Place details not found";
   }
}
search_place_details("kfc");
 ?>
```

but i want to do the same by making use of xml.My xml code looks like this

```
<?php
function  search_place_details($location)
{
$locationclean = str_replace (" ", "+", $location);
$data = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=" . $locationclean . "&key=MY-GOOGLE-API-KEY";
$xml = file_get_contents($data);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

foreach($xml->result->type as $key => $value)
{
$location_details = $value;
echo $location_details;
echo "<br>";
}
}
search_place_details("kfc");
?>
```

both gives the same result but i want to make my xml code to show error message if place details is not found.
Suggestions ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider the following options:

Option 1. Extract status code from Xml results

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$statusCode = (string)$xml->status;
if($statusCode != "OK")
     throw new Exception('Invalid request');
```

Option 2. Convert Xml into Json and verify status code

```
$json = json_encode($xml);
$result = json_decode($json,TRUE);
$statusCode = $result['status'];
if($statusCode != "OK")
    throw new Exception('Invalid request');
```